# using CImg in cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cimg, magick++

i'm trying to open image file for an university project using the [CImg library](http://cimg.eu).
when trying to load a png file, i get a message that the format file is not supported.
after some reading, i tried to install ImageMagick++ and add it as a dependency to my Visual Studio project following this post: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=30295

but it still doesn't work.
how do i add magick++ to my project? (even without the CImg library) is fine.

Comment: Is CImg/ImageMagick required to use?  I have had good success with lodepng which might be a lighter weight alternative.  http://lodev.org/lodepng/

Comment: i tried using lodepng (works great) but i also need bmp and jpg support

Comment: i also tried:
#define cimg_use_magick
#include "CImg.h"

but this gives compilation error for undefined Magick::PixelPacket

Comment: I do not know if you can just install Imagemagick++ without all of Imagemagick. And you need to install a binary that includes the delegate libraries such as PNG, JPG, TIFF otherwise, if you install from source, you would have to manually install these delegates first. Sorry, I do not know CImg or C++.

Comment: i have installed the Imagemagick and marked the developer option during the installation.

Comment: Sounds like your university project is expecting ImageMagick-6. See [Porting to ImageMagick Version 7](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/porting.php). Either uninstall IM-7, and rebuild w/ IM-6, or update the project codebase.

Comment: Just make sure you define `cimg_use_png` in your project settings then CImg can read PNG files itself.